# Double insert in MS Access?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access, insert

I'm somehow getting a double insert; every time I submit the form, it sends two records to the database. I can't figure out what's going on. This is a general idea of what my code looks like:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

'Data collection'

'Define Connection'
    Dim myConn As New OleDbConnection
    myConn.ConnectionString = adsGrandmaster.ConnectionString
    myConn.Open()

'Insert command'
    Dim myIns1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tableGrandmaster (date_received, prefix, course_number, title, new, changed, inactivate, end_date, credits, description, hours_lecture, hours_lec_lab, hours_lab, hours_total, related_instruction, repeat, challengeable, in_catalog, in_printed_schedule, core_course, core_name, program_elective, program_name, prereqs, coreqs, recommended, green_course, code, dept_code, division_code, changing_depts, acti_code, grading, general_ed, writing, social_science, math, information_literacy, arts_letters, science_computer, speech_comm, cultural_literacy, date_curriculum_approval, date_state_sent, date_state_approval, date_created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", myConn)

'Insert parameters'

'Execute command'
    myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery()

'Close connection'
    myConn.Close()
```

**Update:**

The last little piece of my .aspx.vb file:

```
'Execute command'
    myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Label1.Text = "Grandmaster submitted."

    'Close connection'
    myConn.Close()

End Sub

Protected Sub btnBack_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    Response.Redirect("./index.htm")
End Sub
End Class
```

If I place my breakpoint at or before myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery(), nothing inserts. If I place it after myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery(), it inserts once. If I place it after "End Sub" (under myConn.Close()), it inserts twice.

Comment: what on earth are all those question marks for? I'm assuming that `myConn` is a previously asserted database connection

Comment: yes, sorry I left that out of my post, just added it in. and the question marks, I think it's a Microsoft Access thing? I don't know, I haven't really worked with anything besides Access, and this is how I was taught... I assume the normal syntax is @whatever... but I don't think that works for this.

Comment: The question marks are an OleDb's placeholders for parameters.  They are ordinal, not nominal.

Comment: So, this code looks fine.  Can you show us more of the code?  My assumption is that this method is getting called twice, probably because you have added the event twice to the button click.

Comment: Is the `btnSubmit_Click` handler "wired up" twice? Perhaps once in your code and once through the `AutoEventWireup` attribute being set to "true"?

Comment: @Craig do you want me to post the whole code behind file? or the .aspx page?

Comment: @Martin the AutoEventWireup attribute is set to false...

Comment: I might be asking to check something you've already done here, but is the <aspx:button declaration wired up to the onclick event on the code-in-front page too?

Comment: @pb Oh that was it! Thanks! You should put this down as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the aspx:button declaration is not wired up to the onclick event on the code-in-front page as well as the code behind page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting duplicate inserts either the program is calling an insert on the database twice, or the database is causing the duplicate (although this is doubtful as you are not calling a stored procedure that could be hiding the duplication from you).

As the problem is more likely to be caused by the insert in the c# program being called twice add a debug line on your insert line:

```
Dim myIns1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tableGrandmaster (date_received, prefix, course_number, title, new, changed, inactivate, end_date, credits, description, hours_lecture, hours_lec_lab, hours_lab, hours_total, related_instruction, repeat, challengeable, in_catalog, in_printed_schedule, core_course, core_name, program_elective, program_name, prereqs, coreqs, recommended, green_course, code, dept_code, division_code, changing_depts, acti_code, grading, general_ed, writing, social_science, math, information_literacy, arts_letters, science_computer, speech_comm, cultural_literacy, date_curriculum_approval, date_state_sent, date_state_approval, date_created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", myConn)
```

Then run your program in debug mode (press F5 in Visual Studio if you are using it) - if the insert line is run twice then you need to work out why, and take away one of the calls.

Comment: I added a breakpoint after the insert line, and ran it in debug mode and when I do that it seems to only insert once...

Comment: Is there possibly another page that is using similar code (you could search your site for tableGrandmaster) - it may not be this code causing the problem by the sound of it.

Comment: Please check that the event btnSubmit_Click is fired by some other event too.

Comment: I checked, and can't find anything... nothing else in my site uses tableGrandmaster, and btnSubmit_Click doesn't seem to be fired by anything else.

Comment: Did it insert it again after you stepped through `myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: @Bobort No, actually, it looks like it inserts only after running myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery(). And it only inserts once if I add a breakpoint directly after that line.